# Convert timestamp (unix 13 digits) to datetime format of a complet column of a csv file using awk or sed

Tags: date, awk, timestamp

I have a csv file multiple columns. The first columns has timestamps like,

```
1529500027127
1529500027227
1529500027327
1529500027428
1529500027528
1529500027628
1529500027728
```

I know you can do something like that for a specific timestamp:

```
date -d @1529500027528
```

But how can I select all values of the columns and do that? I tried the next command:

```
date -d "$(awk -F , -v OFS=, '$1/=1000')" file.csv
```

I am trying to understand how date command works with other commands.

Comment: First of all special thanks for sharing code here. Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: My input is the first column of the csv file. (1229500027127, for example). My expected output is the timestamp column in datetime format like this `2018/06/20 15:07:07:127`.

Comment: If you are interested, the dataset link is :https://www.kaggle.com/inIT-OWL/versatileproductionsystem?select=Filling_ALL.module.csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since  sample of expected output is not given so could only test it with given 1st column values, written and tested in GNU `awk`. You could use `strftime` function of `awk`, also since OP hs mentioned Input_file is a csv file so mentioning `FS` and `OFS` as `,` here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$1=strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",$1/1000)}1' Input_file
```

***From `man awk` for `strftime`:***

> strftime([format [, timestamp[, utc-flag]]]) Format  timestamp 
>   according to the specification in format.  If utc-flag is present and
>   is non-zero or non-null, the result is in UTC, otherwise the result is
>   in local time.  The timestamp should be of the same form as returned
>   by systime().  If timestamp is missing, the  current  time  of day  is
>   used.   If  format  is  missing,  a  default  format  equivalent  to 
>   the output of date(1) is used.  The default format is available in
>   PROCINFO["strftime"].  See the specification for the strftime()
>   function in ISO C for the format conversions that are guaranteed to be
>   available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an external `date -d@....` command, you could do this:

```
awk -F, -v 'OFS=,' '{"date -d@"$1 | getline timestamp ; $1=timestamp; print}' filename
```

Obviously finding a builtin function to do the same job (in this case, the `strftime` function as suggested by another answer) is a more efficient solution in terms of execution time, but the above gives an example of how to call out to external programs that you may be already familiar with.